# Trying to clean merged JS/CSS cache, but model "core/design_package" is a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9

I have made a new PHP file at the root directory of Magento (next to index.php) and it contains this code:

```
require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::getModel('core/design_package')->cleanMergedJsCss();
```

Produces this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object
in /home/edpadev/public_html/stage/bsr/app/Mage.php on line 463
```

From my understanding, Magento should dig up that particular method in `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php`.
I cannot var_dump it since it cannot instantiate it, I just get the same error when trying to do that.

I am able to call our third-party cache module's observer model and use its methods, and use the simple `Mage::app()->cleanCache();`, but the core function above does not work, though that is how it appears in examples by other developers in Google search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You might need to setup the store

```
 umask(0);
 require 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Comment: That appears to have worked as it did not return any errors. Thank you!